# Google Sheets is unable to open an XML spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, xml-spreadsheet

I have an XML spreadsheet generated using VB.net
I want to open it into Google Sheets, but Google is unable to perform this, and throws the error "Unable to convert".

Is there any way to open an XML spreadsheet using Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try. As suggested in this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/okuDbcrGIeU) try to convert your XML file to Excel sheet first. One of way to do this is use an online converter - [XML to Excel Converter](http://www.luxonsoftware.com/converter/xmltoexcel). After that, you can now try to open the Excel file using Google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here later, I just successfully converted a 96MB XML file using [convertcsv.com](http://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm). The other sites I tried did not allow such a large file, understandably.